# How to get and plot a signal envelope

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I would like to know if there is a function `envelope` in Python to have the same result as this

[image: picture]

I have already tried an `envelope` function in Python but there is this result and it doesn't correspond with what I want.

[image: result]

Comment: I'd say the python one is a better result. What is what you dont like about it?

Comment: I know, but I have to get the falling/rising times and the area and it's easier with this kind of envelope.

Comment: where does this "envelope function in Python" come from ? which library is it ?

Answer (score 2):

Though you don't mention exactly what function you use, it seems like you are using two different kinds of envelopes.

The way you call envelope in matlab, the relevant description is:

> [yupper,ylower] = envelope(x) returns the upper and lower envelopes of
>   the input sequence, x, as the magnitude of its analytic signal. The
>   analytic signal of x is found using the discrete Fourier transform as
>   implemented in hilbert. The function initially removes the mean of x
>   and adds it back after computing the envelopes. If x is a matrix, then
>   envelope operates independently over each column of x.

Based on this, I suppose you would be looking for a way to get the Hilber transform in python. An example of this can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html):

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from scipy.signal import hilbert, chirp

 duration = 1.0
 fs = 400.0
 samples = int(fs*duration)
 t = np.arange(samples) / fs

 signal = chirp(t, 20.0, t[-1], 100.0)
 signal *= (1.0 + 0.5 * np.sin(2.0*np.pi*3.0*t) )

 analytic_signal = hilbert(signal)
 amplitude_envelope = np.abs(analytic_signal)
 instantaneous_phase = np.unwrap(np.angle(analytic_signal))
 instantaneous_frequency = np.diff(instantaneous_phase) / (2.0*np.pi) * fs

 fig = plt.figure()
 ax0 = fig.add_subplot(211)
 ax0.plot(t, signal, label='signal')
 ax0.plot(t, amplitude_envelope, label='envelope')
 ax0.set_xlabel("time in seconds")
 ax0.legend()
 ax1 = fig.add_subplot(212)
 ax1.plot(t[1:], instantaneous_frequency)
 ax1.set_xlabel("time in seconds")
 ax1.set_ylim(0.0, 120.0)
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: You're right ! I have tried your solution and an other with the obspy library and these solutions make the same result as the second picture.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I would use obspy.signal.filter.envelope(data_array); But you can only get the upper line in your given example.
Obspy is a very useful package dealing with seismogram.